# Working with the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html tutorial Destroy fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am progressing through the Blog tutorial. 
As directed, I have this in \views\articles\index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing Articles</h1>
<%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
 </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

And I have this in \controllers\articles_controllers.erb :

```
def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy

  redirect_to articles_path
end
```

Yet when I try to delete, I fail to get any 'Are you sure?' dialog, and the record fails to delete.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have these in your codes:

**Gemfile**

```
gem "jquery-rails"
```

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: Hi amree. I have checked both files. All is in order in both. I am sure that you and the others are right in that Javascript is generally failing. I have tried putting this in index.html.erb and it reports back an error.        <head>
  <div id="noscriptmessage" style="color:red">
   This site requires javascript enabled!
</div>
</head> Still investigating...

Comment: Just to be safe, try your app in Google Incognito Window. This is to ensure no extension is causing this problem. If that doesn't work, try Firefox, just to rule out browser problem

Comment: Hi amree, thank you for this further response. I have tried it as suggested. No change. I have also tried creating a fresh app, just to the point of having a welcome index page with a test javascript line. Problem recurs. Also after I strip out Turbolinks from the gemfile, applications.js and applications.html.erb, doing so based on another post that Turbolinks can affect basic javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the missing point is,

you are going through the show path with

```
article_path(article)
```

as long as the destroy path is processed through a post request, and become in the second instance the destroy path we know, you just should do

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article,
          method: :delete,
          data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi Sam, I have now tried that but unfortunately with no success. It appears to be a general error with JavaScript. Still trying to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

do you have JavaScript disabled in the browser if so turn it on

Comment: Thank you for responding - I have checked. JavaScript is already enabled in browser (Chrome). So that is not the problem.